# ERROR! conflicting action statements with include_vars

Tags: ansible, statements

I try to use a vars-file with the parameter include_vars in my task. Because I will seperate the vars for interfaces/hosts and credentials. Without this option, the task run without syntax error. But if I put this option in my task I get the message:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements

The error appears to have been in '/home/devops/ansible/roles/dev/nrpe_config/tasks/main.yml': line 27, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: copy Check Files for ENV from templates
  ^ here


  The error appears to have been in 
  '/home/devops/ansible/roles/dev/nrpe_config/tasks/main.yml': line 27, 
  column 7, but may be elsewhere in the file  depending on the exact syntax problem.

  The offending line appears to be:


- name: copy  Check Files for ENV from templates
  ^ here
```

My Task:

```
    - name: copy Check Files for Env from templates
      template: src={{item}} dest=/home/nrpe/{{item}} owner=nrpe group=nrpe mode=u+x backup=yes
      with_fileglob:
        - "/etc/ansible/roles/nrpe_config/nrpe_scripts/templates/env/*"
      include_vars: file='interfaces.yml' name=interfaces
```

Tree file

```
 ├── tasks
 │    ├── main.bak
 │    └── main.yml
 └── vars
      ├── interfaces.yml
      └── main.yml
```

Greetings niesel

Answer (score 2):

`include_vars` and `template` are two different modules, you can use them in one task, make two instead:

```
- name: include vars
  include_vars: file='interfaces.yml' name=interfaces

- name: copy Check Files for Env from templates
  template: src={{item}} dest=/home/nrpe/{{item}} owner=nrpe group=nrpe mode=u+x backup=yes
  with_fileglob:
    - "/etc/ansible/roles/nrpe_config/nrpe_scripts/templates/env/*"
```

Comment: Did you mean `you can't use them in one task,` ?